# How to handle negative power in F#?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to build the nth power function in F#. (Yes, there's already `Math.Pow` in .Net). Here is my attempt:

```
let rec nthPower x n =
    match n with 
        | 0 -> 1
        | _ -> x * (nthPower x (n-1))
```

This works fine when `n >= 0`; however, I don't know how to handle the negative case: when n < 0.

Question:

1. How to handle the negative case? (n<0)
2. Is this recursive algorithm efficient? or are there any efficient ways in F#?

Comment: Your type will change to a fraction or a double then. Is that desirable?

Comment: @leppie That's fine. (Thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement it like this:

```
let rec nthPower x n =
    match n with
      | 0 -> 1m
      | t when t < 0 -> 1m / (nthPower x -n)
      | _ -> decimal x * (nthPower x (n - 1));;
```

The `t when t < 0` allows the pattern matching to match a range of values. I would say that the RHS of this line is self-explanatory, but let me know if it's unclear.

Regarding question #2, I don't think there's anything particularly inefficient about this approach and there's probably not a much simpler way to do it. I'm not sure what the most efficient approach is, but hopefully some mathematicians can chime in.

**Edit:** I have found an approach that is more efficient for exponents > ~10. It uses memoization and divide-and-conquer to compute the result in O(log n) time instead of O(n):

```
let rec nthPower x n =
    match n with
      | 0 -> 1.0
      | 1 -> double x
      | t when t < 0 -> 1.0 / (nthPower x -n)
      | _ ->
          let p = nthPower x (n / 2)
          p * p * nthPower x (n % 2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! `t when t < 0` solved my problem. But I found that this function could not calculate large number, say `2^100`. Can we use `bigint` here? or are there anything like `bigfloat`?  (I hope this question is not too stupid:)

Comment: @Nick 2^100 is slightly larger than the maximum value that `decimal` can represent. For large values, you can use a `double` (just replace the two `1m`s with `1.0` and replace the `decimal` with `double`. The downside is that numbers past a certain size will be imprecise due to rounding. `bigint` wouldn't make sense if you want to support negative exponents because negative exponents require supporting fractional values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation! You're so kind to a newbie; and F# community is very friendly.